# Listing all branches/tags from a given SVN revision

Tags: svn

I have a large SVN repository with lots of branches and tag.

Is it possible to list all branches and tags from a specific revision and up?

Comment: What exactly are you intereted in? Are you interested in only current branches? Are you interested in branches that were created after a certain version? Are you interested in both current and deleted branches? If you follow the standard Subversion model, you should be able to use `svn ls $REPO/tags` and `svn ls $REPO/branches` to list what you want. If you only want the tags and branches after a certain point, you'll need to take that output and verify the creation dates of each tag and branch. If you want deleted ones too, it gets even trickier.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is no canonical Subversion way to do that. However, if you all the branches and tags that you are interested in are located in a single (or at least a small number of) directories, you could use bash to extract the desired information:

```
 diff -u <(svn ls URL -r $((REV - 1))) <(svn ls URL) | grep ^+ | tail -n +2 | cut -d + -f 2 | sed "s|^|URL/|"
```

where `URL` is the branches or tags URL you are looking at and `REV` is the first revision you are interested in. Please note that this solution assumes that you are interested only in branches and tags that were created on/after a specific revision *and still exist*.

Comment: 1/ Use PEG-revision, not Operative 2) `REV + 1`, not  `REV - 1` 3) `svn log` before lswill shorten revision list dramatically

Answer (score 0):

I'm too lazy to write ready to use and so hack-ish solution, as Michael done, I'll describe idea of more easy way (with samples from real data - but files as objects, not dirs and this change doesn't matter for solution)

- List of revisions (warning of Michael about single or minimal parent-points still applicable)

> ```
> svn ls -q URL
> ...
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> r166 | lazybadger | 2009-10-29 21:46:40 +0500 (Чт, 29 окт 2009)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> r162 | lazybadger | 2009-10-28 22:40:09 +0500 (Ср, 28 окт 2009)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> r157 | lazybadger | 2009-10-28 19:23:59 +0500 (Ср, 28 окт 2009)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> r154 | lazybadger | 2009-10-28 15:42:29 +0500 (Ср, 28 окт 2009)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> r153 | lazybadger | 2009-10-28 15:25:36 +0500 (Ср, 28 окт 2009)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> r152 | lazybadger | 2009-10-28 15:18:46 +0500 (Ср, 28 окт 2009)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> r151 | lazybadger | 2009-10-28 14:54:32 +0500 (Ср, 28 окт 2009)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> r147 | SdimS | 2009-10-28 14:04:43 +0500 (Ср, 28 окт 2009)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

with piping `| grep -v -- | gawk -F ...` you can get pure list of revisions

> ```
> r162
> r157
> r154
> r153
> r152
> r151
> r147
> ```

for every needed revision $REV you can call

`svn ls URL@$REV >> FILE.WITH.LIST`

Individual ls'es for some amount of starting revisions in my repo

```
svn ls URL@147
spb2.bmp

svn ls URL@151
city.map
spb2.bmp

svn ls URL@152
balakovo.bmp
balashov.bmp
chebo.bmp
city.map
kaluga.bmp
msk.bmp
orenburg.bmp
penza.bmp
r-n-d.bmp
ryazan.bmp
samara.bmp
saransk.bmp
saratov.bmp
saratov2.bmp
spb.bmp
spb2.bmp
tula.bmp
ulianovsk.bmp
volsk.bmp
yaroslavl.bmp
```

Existing more than one revision objects will be repeated in common file and clones can be eliminamed with `sort -u` after all ls and compacted file will have all objects, which are (or just was) in interesting URL.

One limitation of plain ls is missing historical labels - you can't to know, when each object appeared. In this case `svn ls -v` and slightly harder post-processing of list may be needed

```
svn ls URL@157 -v
    157 lazybadg              окт 28  2009 ./
    154 lazybadg         1272 окт 28  2009 Kerch.bmp
    157 lazybadg         1270 окт 28  2009 KrivoyRog.bmp
    157 lazybadg         1270 окт 28  2009 Mariupol.bmp
    152 lazybadg         1270 окт 28  2009 balakovo.bmp
    152 lazybadg         1270 окт 28  2009 balashov.bmp
    152 lazybadg         1270 окт 28  2009 chebo.bmp
    154 lazybadg         1272 окт 28  2009 cherkassy.bmp
    154 lazybadg         1272 окт 28  2009 chernigov.bmp
    157 lazybadg         6467 окт 28  2009 city.map
    154 lazybadg         1272 окт 28  2009 crimea.bmp
```

fields $1 and $7 (in awk-lingua) will be interesting, FILE will have more unique strings ($1 - revision of last modification, for revset and changed some times object you'll have new string for each changing revision), something like (for cleaned file)

```
 151 city.map
 152 city.map
 162 city.map
1300 city.map
```

which you can solve with `sort -k` (note fixed position of second field)